# Find the column name of the highest weighted average

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a DF that looks like this. In the investor columns, 1 means invested and 0 mean no. If there are more than 1 investors invested in a project, we can assume that they share the investment equally (eg: Investor A and B each invested 50000 in project "something"). I want to calculate the total amount that each investor put in and find out who invested the most.

| Project | Invested Amount | Investor A | Investor B | Investor C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Something | 100000 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| Another | 5000000 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| Last | 25000000 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Right now I am thinking of filtering by each investor that has a 1 and then divide by them sum of all the investor column. Here is what I tried but I am still missing something:

```
Investor_A = df[df['Investor A'] == 1]
test = Investor_A['Invested Amount'] / (df.iloc[:,3:5].sum())
```

Expected output:

Investor A would have put in a total of     100000/2 + 25000000/3 = 8383333.33333. Investor B would have put in a total of 100000/2 + 25000000/3 = 8383333.33333. Investor C would have put in a total of 5000000 + 25000000/3 = 13333333.3333 --> **Investor C** invested the most amount of money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `filter()` on the Investor columns and divide the Invested Amount column by the row-wise sum of the Investor columns. Then multiply it by the investors columns again to get the total share of each investor for each item. Then calling `sum()` would find the total investment of each investor and `idxmax()` would fetch the name of the investor.

```py
investors = df.filter(like='Investor')
avg_invested_amount = df['Invested Amount'] / investors.sum(1)
investment_shares = investors.mul(avg_invested_amount, axis=0)
investment_per_investor = investment_shares.sum()
investment_per_investor.idxmax()
#'Investor C'
```

FYI, this code can be written in 2 lines (but much less legible):

```py
investors = df.filter(like='Investor')
investors.mul(investors.sum(1).rdiv(df['Invested Amount']), axis=0).sum().idxmax()
```

N.B. `mul()` (and `add()`, `sub()`, `div()`) allows `axis` parameter that you can use to make the indexes match for vectorized operations (which is not possible for `*`).

Answer (score 2):

@NewEnglandcottontail's way is straights forward... Another way could be this;

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({"Project":["Project1","Project2","Project3"],
                   "Invested Amount":[100000,5000000,25000000],
                   "Investor A":[1,0,1],
                   "Investor B":[1,0,1],
                   "Investor C":[0,1,1]})

df1 = df.copy()
col_lst = [col for col in df1.columns if "Investor" in col]
df1[col_lst] = df1.apply(lambda x: x[col_lst] * x["Invested Amount"]/sum(x[col_lst]),axis=1)

lst = df1[col_lst].sum().to_list()
print("Investor who invested maximum ammount:",col_lst[lst.index(max(lst))])
```

Output;

```
Investor who invested maximum ammount: Investor C
```